# Include compiled C file into Python

Tags: c++, c, python-3.x, unix

I got a compiled C file (let's say testprog) from a person who is not here anymore, which takes 2 parameters when calling. They way I call the file from the unix shell is

```
testprog arg1 arg2
```

where arg1 is a file.

I am creating a GUI using python that generates the arg1 file easily instead of writing it manually. Now my questions are:

1. How do I integrate the compiled C file into my python code, so that I can pass the unix command via python and get the results/output directly?
2. How do I compile everything together (with the compiled C file) so that I can distribute my GUI to other people?

The final target will be providing a single file to users that incorporates my python gui and the compiled C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your 1st problem I reccomend you checkout the `subprocess` package.

```py
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(["testprog", "qrg1", "arg2"])
```

or the [ctypes](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/calling-c-functions-from-python) package which allows you to call c functions from python.
For the second problem, I think you will need to send both the python and compiled `c` for both of my solutions.

edit:
Maybe checkout [py_compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/py_compile.html)